# How to choose the adequate sample width?

Tags: sample-size

I'm conducting some experiments. My aim is to measure the time needed by a board to do some stuff (it is not relevant for my question but, if needed, ask in the comment). The point is that the experiments are very time-consuming (actually, what is time-consuming is the generation of randomized quantities needed in the experiments, but, again, it is not important). So, from my basic knowledge of statistics, I know that there exists a formula that imposes a lower bound to the number of samples needed to have a certain target confidence interval as function of the variation of the outcomes. I found that formula on my professor's handsouts and [here](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/ppc/section3/ppc333.htm) in the section "Estimating location: relative error". What I did so far, basically, was to launch 100 experiments for each configuration (for now 6 configurations) and for each of those I applied that formula with $\alpha = 0.125$ and therefore $z_\alpha \approx -1.95$ and $\delta = 0.1$. The results that I obtained were of two types: in some cases the estimated sample needed were something like 6000 but ok, it would make sense. But in some other cases I obtained some decimal numbers (ex. 0.6 sample) less than 1. Now, it is clear I'm doing some mistake, but where? Thanks to everyone, any contribution is appreciated

Comment: how does your $\sigma$ compare to $\mu$

Comment: @phdmba7of12 I don't understand what you mean..

Comment: $\sigma$ is what you refer to above as "the variation of the outcomes"

Comment: @phdmba7of12 If you look at the formula in the page that I linked you'll know how and why $\sigma$ and $\mu$ appear in the same expression